# Not able to access Model in the View. Used Repository and EntityFramwork

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model, repository

I am creating a MVC4 website named "SaleModule". I have added another project in the solution named "Autonomous_Framwork_Rsoff" in which there is a repository and model (Entity Framework). I have added the reference of "Autonomous_Framwork_Rsoff" in the MVC project. This is the controller code:

```
public ActionResult outletdisplay()
    {
        var dataContext = new AutonomousEntities1();
        var brandRepository = new            Repository<Autonomous_Framework_Rsoff.Brand>(dataContext);
        var outletRepository = new Repository<Autonomous_Framework_Rsoff.Outlet>(dataContext);

        IEnumerable<Autonomous_Framework_Rsoff.Brand> brandList =       brandRepository.GetAll();

        return View(brandRepository);
    }
```

GetAll is a function is repository which would get all the Brands.
Now this is the code of view.

```
@model IEnumerable<Autonomous_Framework_Rsoff.Model1.Brand>
```

But there comes an error in the first line   @ model IEnumerable Red line comes under Model1. Autonomous_Framework_Rsoff.Model1 is not found.

Comment: Why are you adding Model1 to the namespace? Above that you reference the model with Autonomous_Framework_Rsoff.Brand

Comment: Why are you passing "brandRepository" in View method in your controller ? Instead you should pass "brandList". Also like @Steve said, why are you adding Model1 in model namespace ?

Comment: You should use DI here. And as @SteveGreene said the namespace is differs from the one referenced in the controller. I believe if change it to be same as in controller it should work.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, there are two places need to corrected:

```
IEnumerable<Autonomous_Framework_Rsoff.Brand> brandList = brandRepository.GetAll();

return View(brandList);
```

and

```
@model IEnumerable<Autonomous_Framework_Rsoff.Brand>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much it fixed it :)

Comment: @HamnaRashid glad it helps! Can you pls mark it as the answer? Thx.

Comment: I am new dont have  enough reputation to mark it as answer. Once I get it i will come back to do so :)